# How to show Folium map inside a PyQt5 GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, folium

I'm trying to show a very simple Folium map inside a Qt GUI. The main code is:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
m
m.save('index.html')
folium.Map(
    location=[45.5236, -122.6750],
    tiles='Stamen Toner',
    zoom_start=13
)
```

When I use the code with Jupyter it's fine but shows anything with Spyder. What I want is to show the map in a QGraphicsView or any other QClass on a simple Qt GUI?

Comment: Display it in [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html). For an example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494200/984421).

Comment: Is it possible entirely without JS?

Comment: You will probably have to put that Map within a QLabel as that is what PyQt5 uses to hold most images

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save the html in a io.BytesIO() using the save method and then set it to a QWebEngineView using the setHtml() method:

```py
import io
import sys

import folium
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = folium.Map(
        location=[45.5236, -122.6750], tiles="Stamen Toner", zoom_start=13
    )

    data = io.BytesIO()
    m.save(data, close_file=False)

    w = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    w.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: do you know if adding layer is supported with your method ? I'm currently facing some troubles here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204476/folium-map-embedded-within-pyqt-displays-blank-when-adding-geojson-to-layer

Answer (score 3):

HTML string of the map can be passed to the setHtml:

```
import sys
import folium
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750], zoom_start=13)
    w = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    w.setHtml(m.get_root().render())
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```