# How do I create a popup on folium map using data from json file?

Tags: python, pyqt5, folium

How do I go about creating a popup on my folium map to show information about the nodes ? As show below, my folium map is currently drawing the data from a json file that I have downloaded from overpass turbo. Hence the blue outline of the buildings on the map. I am having trouble to create a popup such that when a user click on the building, a popup would appear to display information, like in overpass turbo. Currently, I am trying to retrieve all the information under 
"properties", but my codes does nothing, as when I tried to click on the building, instead of a popup, click on the map will just zoom in instead.

*PS my current GUI is based on a answer provided to me on another question I have posted "[How to include folium map into PyQt5 application window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437182/how-to-include-folium-map-into-pyqt5-application-window)"

**Folium Map**

[image]

**CODE**

```
 with open('exportBuildings.geojson') as access_json:
            read_content = json.load(access_json)

 feature_access = read_content['features']


# Creating folium map
for feature_data in feature_access:
            buildingName = feature_data['properties']

m = folium.Map(location=[1.400150, 103.910172], titles="Punggol", zoom_start=17)
nodeData = os.path.join('exportFULL.geojson')
folium.GeoJson(nodeData).add_child(folium.Popup(buildingName))
folium.GeoJson(nodeData).add_to(m)
data = io.BytesIO()
m.save(data, close_file=False)
self.view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
```

**JSON FORMAT**

```
"type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "way/768461439",
    "building": "train_station",
    "layer": "1",
    "name": "Damai LRT",
    "wikidata": "Q7313275",
    "wikipedia": "en:Damai LRT station"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The problem is that you are creating 2 GeoJSON items:

```
folium.GeoJson(nodeData).add_child(folium.Popup(buildingName))
folium.GeoJson(nodeData).add_to(m)
```

In the first one you add popup as a child but you do not add it to the map, in the second you add it to the map but it does not have popup, that is, only a GeoJson will be seen on the map without popup.

#### Solution:

The solution is to create only a GeoJson where the item is added and the popup is established as a child:

```py
geo_json = folium.GeoJson(nodeData)
geo_json.add_child(folium.Popup(buildingName))
geo_json.add_to(m)
```

that taking advantage of the add_to() and add_child() property that returns the same item can be reduced to:

```py
folium.GeoJson(nodeData).add_to(m).add_child(folium.Popup(buildingName))
```

Or

```py
folium.GeoJson(nodeData).add_child(folium.Popup(buildingName)).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. Now each building is clickable. However, the popup box is empty. Is it probably due to my json file ?

Comment: @DeniseTay If the popup is empty then the only cause is that buildingName is an empty string.. Change `folium.Popup(buildingName)`  to `folium.Popup("Hello World")`

Comment: The buildingName is not an empty string as I have tried it by printing out buildingName and it return me all the information under properties

Comment: @DeniseTay try with: `folium.Popup(str(buildingName))`

Comment: oh it works. thanks. Just checking, even though that I can click all building and it shows the information. I notice all building has the same information.  Is it because of my for loop ? that is retrieving the data from json file

Comment: @DeniseTay 1) the for loop causes buildingName to take the last value. 2) Only one popup can be added to the GeoJson. Conclusion: You can only one information. If you want to show all the information try `buildingName = ",".join([str(feature_data['properties']) for feature_data in feature_access])`

Comment: @DeniseTay On the other hand we are getting out of the subject since your question is concrete: how to show popup and my answer already does, so I will not answer anything else. If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: sorry I understand only 1 popup can be added to geojson but why can't I added name of the building to each node respectively ?