# Folium map embedded within PyQt displays blank when adding GeoJson to layer

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2, qwidget, folium

I have PyQt5 app that embeds a folium Map within a QWidget.

Here's a minimal example of the class I wrote :

```
import folium
import io

from folium.plugins import Draw, MousePosition, HeatMap
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class FoliumMap(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        m = folium.Map(
            title='coastlines',
            zoom_start=3)

        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)
        webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        self.layout.addWidget(webView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

If i run my program here's what I have :
[image]

Now I want to add a GeoJson layer within the `__init__` of my class :

```
folium.GeoJson('data/custom.geo.json', name='coasts').add_to(m)
```

This results in having a blank Qwidget :
[image]

If I save the map under html format I am able to see the layer on my web browser:
[image]

Has anyone an idea on why the layer implementation makes the QWidget blank ? And how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the following command :
`webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())`

It is said in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setHtml) that :

> Content larger than 2 MB cannot be displayed, because setHtml() converts the provided HTML to percent-encoding and places data: in front of it to create the URL that it navigates to. Thereby, the provided code becomes a URL that exceeds the 2 MB limit set by Chromium. If the content is too large, the loadFinished() signal is triggered with success=false.

My html file weighs 2628 KB > 2MB. So we have to use `webView.load()` method instead.

This is the way to go :

```
import folium
import io

from folium.plugins import Draw, MousePosition, HeatMap
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtCore

class FoliumMap(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        m = folium.Map(
            title='coastlines',
            zoom_start=3)
        
        url = "C:/MYPATH/TO/map.html"
        m.save(url)

        webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        html_map = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(url)
        webView.load(html_map)

        self.layout.addWidget(webView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```